# simplifying a product formula (similar to Euler's sine product)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, products

Can anyone help me out trying to simplify the left hand side of the below equation to obtain the right hand side?

$$ 
\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{n=-\infty \\n\neq 0}}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{z/n} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right). 
$$

Comment: Isn't this as simple as combining the terms on the left side with for $n$ and $-n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\left(1-\frac z n\right) e^{z/n} \cdot \left(1+\frac z n\right) e^{-z/n} = 1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}.$$